# Not found af from appFog to download

Tags: appfog

I'd like to download and install af from appFog but when I execute the needed command in the Command Prompt (in Windows) I obtain the next result:

```
    C:\Users\Jose>gem install af
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'af' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect retur
ned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (
https://s3.amazonaws.com/production.s3.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

do any body what is the problem? I have read about the temporal stoped sing up service of appfog, is this the reason?
I have read about the command line exit but I don't have found any response.

Thanks.
Jose

Answer (score 0):

The https source has a certificate error. Add the http version. It will give you a warning but if you add it, it will work.

```
gem source -a http://rubygems.org
```